# time stamp display is incorrect sometimes (database automatically changes time)

Tags: mysql, datetime, grails, timezone, datecreated

I have  a problem with time stamp being displayed.

sometimes actual date-5.30 and
other times +5.30
I do not understand how it is happening to the complete database

At one instance of time the dates are correct
at second instance it is 5.30 hours ahead

I am attaching the snapshots of the two taken back to back.
It is not just +/- 5.30 hrs but sometimes 11 hours ahead to actual  date n time.

I had put the following code to get the IST time in database records.

> BOOTSTRAP- TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")) CONFIG -
>   JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=IST"

My server is in US and the datbase too at the same pc.
I am accessing it from India.
And I want the time in database to be of IST only irrespective of where ever my server may shift.[image: Image 1][image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be depending on the database, or the user.timezone setting to format your dates.

I'd suggest explicitly formatting them with a SimpleDateFormat on which you've called setTimeZone()

Here's an example: http://www.roseindia.net/java/javadate/converting-time-time-zone.shtml

Comment: well, thanks for ur response. I want an explanation actually that why is the time stamp changing? What is the reason behind showing complete databse at a specific time at a instance and then just theres a sudden increase in all. how do I explicitly format the dateCreated field of the database? which is automatically picking up dates?or lastUpdated field?